# JAWS Screen Reader and link to same page

Tags: html, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I'm not even sure that JAWS can do this task but I thought I would ask anyways. I have a link on an HTML page that points to a footnote at the bottom of the page. My page looks like this:

```
some HTML...

<a href='http://www.blah.com.au/controller#footnote1'>

...more HTML...

<p id='footnote1'>
    footnote text
</p>

...more HTML
```

This all works fine, except when I run JAWS over the page. The problem is that that the screen reader begins to read out from the paragraph with `id` of `footnote1`, but it does not stop at the end of the paragraph. It continues to read out the rest of the page. Is there a way you can tell JAWS to just read the `<p>` in question?

Answer (score 0):

I have spoken to two accessibility experts and done a fair bit of Googling and I have come to the conclusion that JAWS can not perform this task.